# Initial label with 'el-select' is not applied

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have the following code using el-select from Element UI framework for Vue.js:

```
<el-select v-model="selectTagPicker" @change="handleTagChange(selectTagPicker)">
     <el-option v-for="(tag, tagIndex) in allTags" :key="tag.id" :value="tagIndex" :label="tag.name">
          {{ tag.name }}
     </el-option>
</el-select>
```

The problem here is that on the first load, the label is not applied, but it shows the value instead (which in my case is just an array index), and the user is always greeted with "0", instead of the tag name (since I always load the first item in the array, and I need to show that as well).

Every subsequent selection of the option from the dropdown is done properly for both values and labels.

How can I make sure to apply a proper label (which should be a tag name), on the first load as well?

Answer (score 4):

The original problem was that the `el-select`'s initial value (via `v-model="selectTagPicker"`) was not found in the `option`s, so `el-select` displayed the unknown value. Given the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50532699/6277151) regarding differing value types and that the `el-select` displayed `0`, the cause was likely that `selectTagPicker` was initialized to `"0"` (a `String`), while the `option` values were all `Number`s:

```html
<template>
  <el-select v-model="selectTagPicker">
    <el-option
        v-for="(tag,tagIndex) in allTags"
        :key="tag.id"
        :value="tagIndex"  Number
        :label="tag.name"
      >
      {{tag.name}}
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allTags: [...],
      selectTagPicker: "0"  String (❌does not match any values)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo of original problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-selecting-first-item-in-el-select-z5ypv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMySelect.vue&theme=dark)

Converting the `option` values to `String` (via `:value="String(tagIndex)"` in the template) resolves the issue because the first item would be assigned `"0"`, matching the inital value of `selectTagPicker`:

```html
<template>
  <el-select v-model="selectTagPicker">
    <el-option
        v-for="(tag,tagIndex) in allTags"
        :key="tag.id"
        :value="String(tagIndex)"  String (✅first value matches `selectTagPicker`)
        :label="tag.name"
      >
      {{tag.name}}
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allTags: [...],
      selectTagPicker: "0"  String
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo of OP's solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-selecting-first-item-in-el-select-jlzkf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMySelect.vue&theme=dark)

Alternatively, the OP could've changed the initial value of `selectTagPicker` to `0` (a `Number`):

```html
<template>
  <el-select v-model="selectTagPicker">
    <el-option
        v-for="(tag,tagIndex) in allTags"
        :key="tag.id"
        :value="tagIndex"  Number
        :label="tag.name"
      >
      {{tag.name}}
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allTags: [...],
      selectTagPicker: 0  Number (✅matches first value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo of alternate solution 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-selecting-first-item-in-el-select-sxlen?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMySelect.vue&theme=dark)

Another solution is to use an existing prop (e.g., `id`) from the option item as the `option`'s value, and then initialize `selectTagPicker` to that prop's value:

```html
<template>
  <el-select v-model="selectTagPicker">
    <el-option
        v-for="tag in allTags"
        :key="tag.id"
        :value="tag.id" 
        :label="tag.name"
      >
      {{tag.name}}
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    const allTags = [...]
    return {
      allTags,
      selectTagPicker: allTags[0].id 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo of alternate solution 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-selecting-first-item-in-el-select-sxlen?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMySelect.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: Wow, those "fingers" in code are simply amazing... <3 <3 <3

Comment: if you set the "persistent" attribute to false it could cause problem in initial state evaluate value-key

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the value type. It was a number and a further calculation was using string.

If you need a string, use: `:value="String(tagIndex)"` or vice versa.